# How to disable UITableViewRowAction (without clicking an edit button)?

Tags: swift3, uitableview

Normally when this function is called, deleting a table view cell by swiping left is allowed:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
    }
}
```

But I created an edit button like this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

and I'd like to enable deleting a cell only when the edit button was clicked and NOT just by swiping. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one `Boolean` instance property with default value `false` and set it to `true` on the action of your `BarButttonItem` after that use that boolean property in `canEditRowAt` method to allow/disallow row edit.

```
var allowEdit = false

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return allowEdit
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot it to set `false` again once your delete is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
    var editMode = false

...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    if editMode == true {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if(editing) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        editMode = true
    }
    else if(!editing) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        editMode = false
    }
}
```

Comment: No need write `if editMode == true {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }` simply one statement is enough `return editMode`